# Parse specific strings (2 strings) from multiple text files from a folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to parse multiple lines which starts with:

> ```
> Procedure = xxxxx::xxxx
> Description = xxxxxx
> ```

Also, I want to ignore `SH Library Procedure = $(Stem)_test` which has same word `Procedure` in the .txt file. 
I want to search all *.txt files and accumulate date in output file which I will use to upload in req management tool.

Here is the sample of the file:

> ```
> Harness Lib Greenhills BLD Add Excluded Files = FALSE
> Harness Lib Template Project File = 
> Harness Lib Generated Project File = 
> Harness Lib Generate Compiler Project File = FALSE
> SH Library Procedure = $(Stem)_test
> Harness Lib Source Lists Add Excluded Files = FALSE
> Harness Lib Substitute Unused Source Files = FALSE
> Macro Standard 1 = Set TBRUN_MACRO_STANDARD_1 in Testbed.ini
>   Procedure = sander_class::sander_class
>   Member Of = 1
>   Creation Date = Jun 21 2019 14:36:44
>   Description = This test is to verify that constructor is called. Req Tested:  67060-SWINTR-73
> ```

I have tried below code, but it does not print `Procedure` and in specific format.

```
@echo off
(
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('find "Procedure =" ^< "TEST.txt"') do (
        for /f "tokens=1,*" %%d in ('find "Description =" ^< "TEST.txt"') do (
            for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%c in ("%%b") do (
                echo(Procedure %%~nxc
                echo(
                echo(Procedure %%a
                echo(
                echo(Description %%d
                echo(
                echo(Path: %%~pb
                echo(
        )
    )
)>"output file.txt"
pause
```

I need output in below format for all the files (.txt) in same folder:

> ```
> File Name = 
> Procedure = sander_class::sander_class
> Description = This test is to verify that constructor is called. Req Tested:  67060-SWINTR-73
> ```

Comment: I tried to improve formatting of the text file contents, please check and feel free to re-[edit]. Also I introduced some indentation to the code, which immediately makes clear that a closing `)` is missing. Anyway, your code does not reflect your desired output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q57185510.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (
 'findstr /R /b /C:" *Procedure =" /c:" *Description =" "%filename1%" '
 ) DO ECHO %%a
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q57185510.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as `%outfile%`

I used the one specific file for testing; for all files then set `filename1` to a filemask like `*.txt`.

The `findstr` looks in all files matching `filename1` for lines that `/b` begin with `/r` regular-expressions `/c:"regex-string"` the "regex-string". "regex" here is a small subset of regular expressions, but the particular expressions of interest are for instance <kbd>Space</kbd>(any number of)Procedure<kbd>Space</kbd>= which matches the two lines in question.

The `tokens=*` suppresses the leading spaces, producing the required lines.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. It works.Now i am moving step ahead to ask the user to enter the filename and path.  Is there a way i can create a Config file, if i need to give multiple filename and path as input...because i will have many files which i need to process at one time? then use this content to copy in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, This should do it but I can't test at the moment.

```
@(
  ECHO OFF
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET "_FilePath=C:\Admin"
  SET "_FileGlob=*.txt"
  SET "_MatchRegex1=Procedure =.*::.*$"
  SET "_MatchRegex2=Description = .*::.*$"
  SET "_ExcludeRegex=^SH Library Procedure =.*$"
  SET "_OutputFile=%Temp%\output file.txt"
)

FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%A IN ('
  DIR /A-D /S /B "%_FilePath%\%_FileGlob%"
') DO (
  SET "_FileName=%%~nxA"
  SET "_CurrentFile=!_FileName: =_!"
  FOR /F "Tokens=1*" %%a IN ('
    FindStr /I /R
    /C:"%_MatchRegex1%"
    /C:"%_MatchRegex2%"
    "%%A"
    ^| FindStr /I /R /V
    /C:"%_ExcludeRegex%"
  ') DO (
    IF NOT DEFINED !_CurrentFile! (
      SET "!_CurrentFile!=Found"
      ECHO.File Name: !_FileName!
    )
    ECHO.%%a %%b
  )
)>> "_OutputFile"
PAUSE
```

I will have to come back through and write up exactly what is being done in more detail if needed.

Essentially I am just using a loop of a DIR command to find all of the .txt files in all directories and subdirectories under the given path.

Then I parse that pull out the file name portion and create a variable I can use to match if the file has already been parsed before so that we only print the file name once.

I don't want to print file names at all unless a match was made because I don't think you care to see long lists of files with no matches, but if you prefer that the logic to test if the file name was found previously can be removed and you can just spit out the file name in the first loop

The second loop is looping the results of running a FindStr command on the given file found in the first loop and matching the Regexes which should mean at least two entries per file more if there are more procedures.

FindStr allows sRegex Matches and /V means to exclude any string that matches and pass the rest.